# Cannot unpack non-iterable 'datetime.time'

Tags: python, pandas, excel, datetime

My primary question is: **How can one iterate over a column full of dates?**

```
# Assume an excel file with one column called 'Time' that contains datetime.time values
df = pd.read_excel("some/file.xls")
for index, time in df['Time']:
    println(time + " " + index)

# OR


for index, time in enumerate(df['Time']):
    println(time + " " + index)
```

but both end up with `cannot unpack non-iterable 'datetime.time' object`. There is gotta be a way to just loop through a column in `DataFrame`...

The reason I want to loop through them is to check if the time includes milliseconds and if not add `.000000` to the value. Which leads to my second related question.

Secondary question: **If I cannot loop through a `datetime.time` object how can I force `to_datetime()` when the format is not the same?**

I have two formats: `%H:%M:%S.%f` and `%H:%M:%S`. Setting format to mixed doesnt work. Apply also doesnt work (same error that datetime.time is not iterable)

```
def date_formatter(date):
   if '.' in date:
      return ... # %H:%M:%S.%f
   else
      return ... # %H:%M:%S

df['Time'].apply(date_formatter)
```

This is a basic functionality, I dont understand hy this has to be so hard.
I can do this perfectly fine in .csv file as the values are string.
Note: The Date column in excel is a formula (e.g. =A1-A2, =B1-B2,...)

Comment: `for index, time in df['Time'].items():`?

Comment: "*check if the time includes milliseconds and if not add .000000 to the value*" - did you consider doing this without an iteration, i.e. with a vectorized pandas method ? Also, why would you add zero? That shouldn't change much ...

Comment: besides, "*I have two formats: %H:%M:%S.%f and %H:%M:%S*" - there might be a misconceptions here; if your Series is of type datetime.time, then it has no format. datetime.time is a data structure to represent time. Only time in a string has a certain "format". The fractional seconds just might not be *displayed* if they are zero.

Comment: @FObersteiner then maybe I am asking completely wrong questions. I mentioned the time format and I am adding zeros so `to_datetime()` and get difference between two times. This is what I was doing when the same files came in .csv format and the values were all just String. Now that I am describing it to you, should I be able to just do basic math subtraction...? datetime.time - datetime.time = milliseconds?

Comment: In comparison to csv which is just strings, excel likes to add some "magic"; date/time columns might already be of type excel serial date (check the formatting options in excel). If you load that as a pandas DataFrame, the column is of a (date)time type already by default, you don't need to parse string --> (date)time. I'm still unsure what your goal is, so not sure if this helps ^^